# How to make Entity Framework to call DB just once for the given code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have to check existance of PatientChartImage in PatientChartImage table.If Images exists i am  assigning it to a existing object. I am using the following code in EF 4.0

```
IEnumerable<PatientChartImage> pcimages = from pcImage in context.PatientChartImages
                                        where pcImage.PatientImageID == id
                                        select pcImage;
if (pcimages.Any())
{
   pcimage = pcimages.First();                                        
   isNewImage = false;
}
else
{ 
   isNewImage = true; 
}
```

Sql Profiler shows 2 calls

1. first is for pcimages.Any()
2. second is for pcimages.First()

How can i make this code to call DB only Once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`FirstOrDefault()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301896.aspx) instead:

> Returns the first element of a
>   sequence, or a default value if the
>   sequence contains no elements.

```
PatientChartImage pcimage = (from pcImage in context.PatientChartImages
                                  where pcImage.PatientImageID == id
                                  select pcImage).FirstOrDefault();
isNewImage = pcimage!=null;
```

Personally I would use lambda syntax in this case:

```
PatientChartImage pcimage = context.PatientChartImages
                                   .Where( x => x.PatientImageID == id)
                                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about doing something like this:

```
pcimage = pcimages.FirstOrDefault();
isNewImage = pcimage != null;
```

Calling first or default will return null if there are no available images, or the first image in the query sequence.  This should result in just a single DB hit.

Comment: +1: your answer was 57 secs faster :-) than mine with exactly the same code:-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var pcimage = (from pcImage in context.PatientChartImages
                                        where pcImage.PatientImageID == id
                                        select pcImage).FirstOrDefault();

isNewImage = pcimage != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

call pcimages.FirstOrDefault()  then check if this is null before doing you processing.

something like this

```
pcimage = pcimages.FirstOrDefault();
if (pcimage != null) {    
   isNewImage = false;
} else {     
   isNewImage = true;  
}
```